# What is "__init__.php"?

Tags: php, composer-php

I downloaded a library and the sample code says to use:

```
require "php-webdriver/lib/__init__.php";
```

Looking in the `php-webdriver/lib/` directory, I do not see this `__init__.php` file.

Does this have something to do with me downloading the library rather than installing it via Composer?

Comment: is this u are looking ?

https://github.com/silverstripe-archive/spec-by-example/blob/master/features/support/php-webdriver/__init__.php

Comment: looks like somethng you need to create with what you wanted to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work like auto-loader class in php.
Copy and paste below code in file named **init**.php
[Github](https://github.com/silverstripe-archive/spec-by-example/blob/master/features/support/php-webdriver/__init__.php)